# Creating an SRE Testing Interview VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-monitoring, stress-testing

I'm working on hiring for a Site Reliability Engineering role and I want to create a "broken" VM for them to log into and debug.

What sort of scenarios would you suggest I put in place to accurately test an applicant's knowledge of Linux command line and basic web server (LAMP) functionality?

We run an Ubuntu environment on AWS.

Comment: How about a real problem you've had in the past?

Comment: I was thinking more on a practical, specific level - like, is there a way to corrupt the filesystem subtly, or misconfigure something that isn't obvious at first glance and allows nginx to run but not work, or things like that.

Comment: break dns in a discoverable way while running stuff that needs resolution (certificates with *ocsp-must-staple* come to mind)

Answer (score 3):

*edit* replace SELinux with AppArmor for Ubuntu

Here are a few suggestion that should be easy to set up in a VM (and I ran into over the years):

- set invalid POSIX permissions for content the web server should deliver.
- set invalid SELinux labels for content.
- break the connection between web server and a backend server (e.g. with IPTables or SELinux)
- as @anx suggested break DNS with `/etc/hosts` entries or invalid nameservers
- create an invalid virtual host / SNI config, making the web server reply with an incorrect vhosts' content.
- create a resource exhaustion scenario invoking the OOM-Killer.
- Block inbound connections with firewalld/iptables/nftables/SELinux.
- Create a config missing content - e.g. missing user and homedirectory, missing content, misspelled ip addresses or directory names, etc.
- Block outbound connections and serve an app from the webserver that needs them.
- Stop and disable needed services - e.g. the DB server.
- Scramble the app's db user's password or introduce a typo.
- Remove grants for the app db user.
- Fill up the filesystem.
- Introduce a failure state in the application depending on text encoding and collation (e.g. jumbled up characters, missing data).